# Weird netcat (OpenBSD version) behavior

Tags: linux, ubuntu, netcat

I am using Ubuntu server 16.04.3, it comes with the OpenBSD version of netcat.

I have used the OpenBSD version of netcat before in Fedora, and in Fedora I can't use the `-p` option with the `-l` option, for example the following is illegal:

```
nc -l -p 12345
```

But in Ubuntu server 16.04.3, the above command worked (by "worked", I mean netcat started listening)!

Even though `man nc` on Ubuntu server 16.04.3 itself says that it is illegal:

[image]

Why is this happening?!

Comment: Obviously a doc bug, since `-s` and `-z` in manpage both mentioned  "It is an error to use this option conjunction with the -l option.", but not `-p`.

Comment: And you can check the fedora rpm `nc` source code at http://vault.centos.org/6.9/os/Source/SPackages/nc-1.84-24.el6.src.rpm, you will noticed `-p and -l` checking code is inside `netcat.c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because the Debian/Ubuntu version of "netcat-openbsd" *is not* in fact the OpenBSD code.  It is the OpenBSD code significantly patched with Debian/Ubuntu changes, which have not been sent back to the maintainers of the original software.

One of those changes, written by Debian person Aron Xu, makes it possible to use the `-p` option with the `-l` option.  As is alas usual, this patch is a half-done job, and does not fix the doco to match the program.

With the vanilla programs, this is impossible, as documented.

## Further reading

- https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/netcat-openbsd.git/log/debian/patches/0011-misc-failures-and-features.patch
- https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/netcat-openbsd.git/tree/debian/patches/misc-failures-and-features.patch